# bash assign variable inside if condition

Tags: bash

In C, it is possible to assign a variable inside an `if` condition, like this:

```
if ( (age = now - mdate) > 7 ) {
    # use variable `age`
}
```

**Is it possible to do this in bash?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but it has nothing to do with the `if` statement.

Inside an arithmetic statement, you can assign to variables.

```
now=10
mdate=1
if (( (age=now - mdate) > 7 )); then
    echo "$age"
fi
```

Here, `(( ... ))` is a command whose content is evaluated as an arithmetic expression. It's unrelated to the `if` statement's syntax, e.g.

```
(( age=10 ))
(( wait = 16 - age ))
echo "$wait years until you can drive"
```

Less `bash`-specific, you can break the condition into multiple commands:

```
# This works in any POSIX-compliant shell
if age=$((now - date)); [ "$age" -gt 7 ]; then
    echo "$age"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(( .. ))`:

```
if (( (age = now - mdate) > 7 )); then
   echo "more than 7"
fi
```